# Should someone obey his step-parents?

Tags: hadith, parents

Is it necessary for someone to obey his parents ( stepfather and stepmother)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should obey your stepparents otherwise it would lead to conflict. However it is not obligatory. Obedience is only obligatory towards biological parents. Regarding the rights between stepparents and stepchildren, the scholars at [Islam-QA](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/104805/rights-and-duties-of-the-mothers-husband-and-the-stepdaughter) say:

> But spending on maintenance, serving and obeying are not obligatory between them.

It may become obligatory if your real parents tell you to obey your stepparents.

Answer (score -2):

Why not? 100% if they treat you like their own children. If they dont then still we should try to keep our home environment peaceful by tackling the situations wisely.

Comment: Should we obey them like our own parents in every situation?what if I have two or three mother,will it be not difficult to obey them all?

Comment: That sounds quite unrealistic to live with two or three mothers in one home in today's world.